# Are there any websites listing travel deals originating in Denmark and Sweden?

Tags: budget, online-resources, sweden, denmark

I know there are websites in Europe that search travel offers from all tour operators/agencie/etc and post the best offers on their website (such as [holidaypirates](http://www.holidaypirates.com/) in the UK)

Are there similar websites like that in Denmark or Sweden?

Comment: Do you wish to find cheap tours to/from Denmark or Sweden? Or would you like a Danish/Swedish website?

Comment: I would like to know if there is a Danish/Swedish website

Comment: Did you check here?  http://forum.bonusfeber.dk/threads/travel-deals-websites-in-denmark-or-sweden.1335/  It looks pretty helpful

Comment: Yes, I posted this question as well in this forum, thank you

Comment: These pirates are quite international.  I know them as the "Urlaubspiraten" from Germany.  Apparently they also have a Swedish branch: http://www.semesterpiraterna.se